# Using relations

Tags: qgis, relation

I am using QGIS, version 3.24.0. I have a shapefile called "Map_CorrectionDEF", uniquely identify by fields "GID" and "unitcode". It is a grid cell, in which the field "GID" is the cell and "unitcode" the country to which the cell belongs.

On the other hand, I have a CSV file, called crop_main (no geometry), uniquely identify by "unitcode" and "cropclass", where "unitcode" refers to the country and "cropclass" the type of crop.

I present an example of my CSV file:

[image]

I want to connect both fields. I would like to assign to each cell the type of crop which exist in the country which the cell belongs. More specific, for each cell, which belongs to a country ("unitcode" field), I would like to join every value of my csv file with has the same value of "unitcode". The goal is to obtain for all the cells of my shape file the information of all cropland which grows in the country. Hence, all the cells of the same country should have the same number of crops.

To do it (I am not sure if the correct way), I am doing the following relations:

[image]

However, when I do it, I am not able to visualize the relation I am creating. According to this, https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html?#creating-one-or-many-to-many-relations "depending on your settings, the form might open directly or you will have to choose to open it in the identification dialog under actions." In my case it's not open directly, but I am not able to go to the identification dialog.

I add a screenshot of what I see when I click one my cells in the map after doing the relation which @J.R proposed in his answer.

[image]

Second edit: I attach an screenshot of how I try to match the 1:many with aggregate function according to [1n-relations-in-label-expressions-general-syntax](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320954/1n-relations-in-label-expressions-general-syntax)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to set the two layer (parent : "Map_CorrectionDEF",  and child : "crop_main") then set the field that link them, in your case the country field: "unitcode" for both layer.

This way when you click in a cell you will see all entry from the CSV table that share the same unitcode (be aware that relation don't work like join, you wont get the CSV column added to your grid table but you will see a form with, on top the grid attribute and below an extract of the attribute table of related CSV entry. see image below for example from [QGIS doc on relation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#defining-1-n-relations))

[image]

If your goal is to get a field in your grid table with a list of all crop for the country you may try the solution from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320954/1n-relations-in-label-expressions-general-syntax)

Comment: Hi @J.R, thank you for your answer. When I do the relation just for "unitcode" and I select one of my cells, I just see a different numbers of cells, not the crops. I have edited my question with that.

Comment: Yes, my goal is to have a new field in my cells with the list of all crops which belongs to the country. If I have a country with two crops, I would like that all the cells which belongs to that country has two new observations with that two crops. Its like join the two rows of my csv (as I put in my question)

Comment: @OgeiD I have modified the link at the end (it's for label but the same expression should work in field calculator). For seeing the same as in my picture you just need to click on the top left icon of the identify result panel to open the form (you may click on the wrench icon on the left to set it to automatically open)

Comment: Thanks @J.R, I feel a bit stupid with myself but when I select a cell, I go to the identify result panel and I click the top left icon, that says "view feature form", I do not see that picture. I updated the picture I see when I do that.

Comment: Thanks for the new link. I will try to do it. However, I have a doubt because it seems that is a 1:many, but I really want a 1:many ? I do not have just one unit to match. I have a lot of cells by country in the shapefile and on the other hand, I have different crops in the csv file. This is why I tried with a relation (according to my readings). But I am new in QGIS and this is really difficult for me to do it.

Comment: Yes you are doing one to many as for each cell (1) you will get many crop (in reality you are doing many to many as each crop could belong to several cell but for your purpose it doesn't matter). For what you see in the form check the attribute form properties (in the grid layer properties, attribute form tab), it could be set either to autogenerate (then you should get the same as me) or to drag and drop designer then make sure to add the relation to the form (drag the relation from the available widgets column to the form layout column)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am trying to do it with the aggregate function of the link you sent to me but I am not able to do it. I attach a screenshot about what I am doing. Do you know what I am doing wrong? I have tried to follow the instructions.

Comment: You forget to remplace the @parent value by 'Map_CorrectionDEF'

Comment: Thank you @ J.R . I did it but it's also say that the expression is invalid. It added: "Eval Error: Could not calculate aggregate for: "cropclass" (Cannot calculate concatenate on numeric fields".

Comment: try to remplace expression:="cropclass" by expression:=to_string("cropclass")

Comment: Thank you @J.R . I did it. It seems there is not any problem but it does not produce any effect. When I go to the attribute table, there is nothing added. I have updated in my question what I type in the Field Calculator

Comment: Dont you think that I should open a new question with exactly what I would like to obtain (now that I know is not possible to do with a relations) and how I am trying to do it in order to understand why I am doing wrong?