# Problem using aggregate function to do a 1:m join

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, aggregate

I am using QGIS, version 3.24.0. I have a shapefile called "Map_CorrectionDEF", uniquely identify by fields "GID" and "unitcode". It is a grid cell, in which the field "GID" is the cell and "unitcode" the country to which the cell belongs.

On the other hand, I have a CSV file, called crop_main (no geometry), uniquely identify by "unitcode" and "cropclass", where "unitcode" refers to the country and "cropclass" the type of crop.

I present an example of my CSV file:

[image]

I would like to added the CSV column to my grid table. Specifically, I would like to assign to each cell the type of crop which exist in the country which the cell belongs. Then, for each cell, which belongs to a country ("unitcode" field), I would like to join the columns of my csv file which has the same value of "unitcode". The goal is to obtain for all the cells of my shape file the information of all cropland which grows in the country. Hence, all the cells of the same country should have the same number of crops.

I think I am doing a one to many because for each cell, I would like to get many crop. Nevertheless, I have many cells for each country, so I think it should be a many to many. I am trying to do this solution discussed here [1:n relations in label expressions & general syntax](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320954/1n-relations-in-label-expressions-general-syntax) using aggregate function. However, I am not able to get what I want.

I attach a screenshot of what I am doing. It seems everything is ok but when I press ok, nothing happens. Any ideas of what can be happening?

[image]

[Edit: I have still some problems once I apply the answer of @J.R, I attach some screenshot of what I am doing]

Relation:

[image]

Expression:

[image]

No results:

[image]

Comment: good idea to open a new question, I may have mislead you in my previous answer, this one should work...

Comment: In your screengrab there are no field selected below the "update existing field" did you select a suitable (text with enough length) field ?

Comment: Should I do that or create a new field? I would like to join some columns, neither updated an existing file nor create a new field.

Comment: The closest you can get is to create a virtual field (Select "Create a new field" then select "Create virtual field" below) give it a name and choose the field type as text (Virtual field may be slow but will auto-update if you made change in one of your two layer)

Comment: Also did you have any null value in one of the 3 field ( "cropclass" and the two "unitcode") used ? if yes that may causes problem

Comment: Thank you @J.R so much because I was desperate. It seems that it works. I did just with "Create a new field" because when I also selected the virtual one, QGIS does not work very well, it gives me some problems. If I want to add the rest of the columns of the csv to my grid table, can I add them in the "expression"? After I will have to split by , and making new fields instead of one separating by ,. Thank you so much again

Comment: In principle, it not should be any null value but I will pay attention to that.

Comment: If you want to add other field you may use the same expression, just use the name of the field you want to get after the "expression:=" part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the [solution in the referenced](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/320954/1n-relations-in-label-expressions-general-syntax) question to work you need to define the relationship between your two layer before attempting to use the expression.

Your first steep is to go to Project > Properties... then to select the Relation tab. Here you will add a relation with the "Map_CorrectionDEF" layer as parent layer and the "crop_main" as the child, set the "unitcode" field for both the parent and child layer.

Then you should be able to use the expression :

```
aggregate( layer:= 'crop_main',
            aggregate:='concatenate', 
            expression:="cropclass",    
            concatenator:=', ',
            filter:=attribute(  $currentfeature ,'unitcode')=attribute(  @parent ,'unitcode'))
```

The result would be for each cell of the grid layer a list of all cropclass from the crop_main table that share the same unitcode. This should work with both text and numeric field (it does work with my 3.22.1 QGIS version) and you should not replace the @parent with with the parent layer name (the @parent is in reference to the relation you set as a first-steep).

Take care to properly define the field where the result should go as text with enough length to accommodate all the value you expect to aggregate (including the concatenator sting)

Comment: Thank you @J.R . I am doing that but I do not see any effect once I establish the relation and I use the expression. I also has to establish to_string in "expression:= to_string("cropclass"), otherwise it does not work. I will edit to attach a couple of screenshot in case I am doing something wrong